# React rendering JSON instead of component on page reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I've deployed my MERN app on Heroku and everything was fine until I realized an issue every time I refresh the page or try to access a route from the address bar. While navigation through React Router links is fine, trying to go directly to a route from URL address bar or refreshing the page is causing the app to break and sending server responses directly to the browser instead of rendering the component - to clarify: if a given route was supposed to make a `GET request` and display some data, the actual `JSON` is displayed on-screen.

As far as I've checked, this is happening only on components that make a `GET request`.

**server.js**

```
// INITIATE APP
const app = express();

// MIDDLEWARE
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());
app.use(passport.initialize());

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

// Priority serve any static files
isProduction &&
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build")));

// CONNECT TO DATABASE
// db config
const dbConnection = isProduction
  ? process.env.MONGO_URI_PROD
  : process.env.MONGO_URI_DEV;

mongoose.connect(dbConnection, () => {
  console.log("Successfully connected to database");
});

// ROUTES
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");
const detailsRouter = require("./routes/details");
const diaryRouter = require("./routes/diary");
const resultsRouter = require("./routes/results");
const settingsRouter = require("./routes/settings");

app.use("/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/details", detailsRouter);
app.use("/diary", diaryRouter);
app.use("/results", resultsRouter);
app.use("/settings", settingsRouter);

// All remaining requests return the React app, so it can handle routing
isProduction &&
  app.get("*", function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build", "index.html"));
  });

// DEFINE PORTS
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// START SERVER
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

By the end of the code above, right before `Define ports`, there is this statement that I included to fix a similar issue happening on other routes too. I thought this was going to prevent this error in any situation, but it seems that this isn't the case. You can try the app [here](https://cine-log.herokuapp.com) (you can delete the account on `/settings` after testing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to thank [S. Elliott Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15166563/s-elliott-johnson) for the solution I'll post below to anyone running into the same issue in the future:

> This sounds like intended behavior. Your server routes and your React
> Router routes SHOULD NOT conflict.
>
> React Router isn't actually "routing" anywhere from a HTTP sense --
> it's just rendering different JavaScript/HTML and storing its
> "location" in the URL.
>
> When running a React app, the React app is typically only served from
> the root of your website (or some other "root", like
> mydomain.com/app). When you make a `HTTP GET` request to that route, the
> backend server sends all of the JavaScript, HTML, and CSS necessary to
> bootstrap your React app. Clicking around using React Router simply
> causes your React code to run on the client.
>
> When you actually reload the page, your browser, as you know, makes a
> `GET` request back to the server for that route, so you just get
> whatever your server sends. Let's use a few examples where you have a
> React app that's served from my domain.com.
>
> Example 1:
>
> - User makes a browser GET request to mydomain.com. They receive the
>   React app back
> - User navigates to `/auth/login` - no `HTTP` requests, React simply running
>   code
> - User navigates to `/me` to view their account -- again, same
> - User reloads the page using the browser - a `HTTP GET` request is sent
>   to the backend, and they'll receive whatever the backend sends back --
>   whether that's `JSON` or something else
>
> You really have two options here:
>
> 1. Redirect all `HTTP` requests to root, meaning `/`, `/something` and
>    `/anything` will serve `/`. Then host your API on another subdomain, like
>    api.mydomain.com
> 2. Choose a route to serve your API from, like `mydomain.com/api`. Forward
>    all requests from any route EXCEPT `/api` and it's subroutes to the
>    root.

What I ended up doing was option 2:

Renamed my API routes prepending `/api` to all of them on `server.js`. Then I renamed all API calls on React accordingly. That code excerpt

```
isProduction &&
  app.get("*", function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build", "index.html"));
  });
```

on `server.js` took care of the `GET` requests executed on page refresh, making sure that Node always serves `index.html` to supply those requests.

Comment: Absolute legend!