# Getting raw json as output in react app in the browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, mern

I am building a blog app using mern stack.To fetch the data from  backend i am using axios. For state management i am using react-redux.
For the first time i open any page of, it renders correctly. Image below :
[image]

And after auto-refresh i  am just getting the raw data in the browser. like this :

[image]

I am getting this raw json output on every page. (not in the first rendering of the page).

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70628667/react-rendering-json-instead-of-component-on-page-reload)

Comment: Thanks got the answer, just had to have the different URL for backend and frontend

Comment: you welcome! you can add it as an answer to help others  getting the same error