# MERN app display JSON data instead of page on reload

Tags: reactjs, vite, mime-types, mern

I created a web app using MERN stack (React app was created with Vite). Locally everything works fine, but on the server, I keep having a bunch of bugs (I'm on Hostinger VPS).

At first, I had a MIME Type error on my js import in index.html. This was the error message :

> Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"

I solve this problem by replacing this code in my `server.js`:

```
app.get("*", function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/dist", "index.html"));
  });
```

by this one :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/dist/")));
```

At first, everything is working just fine, but when I reload the page, I get a JSON output from the server and not my page. Same thing if I'm going to an unknown url, instead of my custom 404 page, the 404 page error from the server displays (blank page with only 404 written).

I found this subject : [React rendering JSON instead of component on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70628667/react-rendering-json-instead-of-component-on-page-reload)

But I cannot understand what I'm supposed to do.

I already tried everything about a path problem for the first bug, like changing to absolute or relative path, or add this in my `vite.config.js`:

```
export default {
  base: './',
};
```

Oh and my files architecture is like this :

```
- client
 -- dist
 -- public
 -- src
- server
 -- db
 -- routes
 -- server.js
```

I'm currently at work so I don't have access to some files which aren't on my Github repo, but I can provide them if needed later in the day (for instance, `server.js` which is not up-to-date on GitHub).

My Github repo: https://github.com/manonBr/manonautrice

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your git repo and also the other Question you had linked up. When you reload, the client makes a get request to your backend, so it's sending back the data, don't make conflictions with React routes and Backend Routes. Your git repo had "/" this route conflicting, so when doing a hard refresh, an HTTP get request was being sent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you're refering to this line in server.js : 
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("Home page"))

it's now replaced with :
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/dist/")));

(That's the not up-to-date line in my github repo)